# the socket server configed in listener class block up the tomcat running

Tags: java, spring, serversocket

i tried to create a web project about socket communication,but the tomcat got stuck int the running.i put the server class in a listener class to initiate when the project initiates.  But i meet a problem that  it seems the spring config xml didn't initiate.
i guess that the server class keeps listening all the time  blocked up the tomcat running .
How can i solve this problem?
the main code of web.xml

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>socket.ServerListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stock"/"stocked"? Could you explain a bit more exactly what is happening (or not happening)?

Comment: i mean tomcat get stuck,sorry for misspelling

Comment: You can edit your post to correct it, there's an "edit" link right below the tags. But please add more details. "stuck" doesn't really describe anything

Comment: Have you tried starting tomcat in debug mode and setting breakpoints in your classes and checking whether there's a bit of the initialisation code in your classes that doesn't finish?

Comment: i have tried the debug mode.It turns out the sessionFactory is always null.So i guess the spring config xml didn't initiate.

Comment: Is your server running in a dedicated thread ?

Comment: I don't think it's  the cause of my problem.I just want to know how can i keep the server class listening all the time since the project starts without blocking up the tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling accept() in the same thread that called your listener, of course Tomcat gets blocked. Tomcat can't continue until your listener method returns.

Moral: don't do that. Use a separate thread.

Comment: It seems to be a right way.Could you tell me more details about how to do it.If I should stop the server thread for a moment?

Comment: @Dumlys You shouldn't stop the server thread *at all,* that's what I'm telling you. Start a separate thread to do the `accept()`-ing, and another one per accepted socket.